# Fetch and build libpng-android from CMake

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, libpng

I'm developing a C++ library for Android, and I have as dependency the libpng. I'm using the modified library for Android https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android.git, which has a build.sh file in order to compile for the different architectures. Or it can be compiled using **ndk-build**.

I'm Fetching the library from CMake using FetchContent, this effectively download the sources files, but it doesn't build properly. I'm setting the `BUILD_COMMAND` but it doesn't work.

```
FetchContent_Declare( png
        GIT_REPOSITORY      https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android.git
        GIT_TAG             master
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED TRUE
        STEP_TARGETS        update
        BUILD_COMMAND       "${NDK_PATH}/ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${png_SOURCE_DIR}"

FetchContent_GetProperties(png)
if (NOT png_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(png)
    add_subdirectory("${png_SOURCE_DIR}" "${png_BINARY_DIR}" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

It seems that the `BUILD_COMMAND` do nothing.

So, How can I fetch and build the libpng-android from CMake, and then import that result as an imported library?

Comment: The function `FetchContent_Declare` is used for download subproject's sources immediately(at **configure** stage), so they could be **configured** and **build** as a **part of the main project**, via `add_subdirectory`. You, probably, confuse `FetchContent_Declare` with `ExternalProject_Add` function, which performs all steps of the subproject: download, configure, build, but does that only on a **build** stage of the main project. If you want to perform all these steps at **configuration** stage of the main project, just use `execute_process` command.

Answer (score 2):

To complete the Tsyvarev comment with references, according to the doc...

> The following options are explicitly prohibited (they are disabled by the
> FetchContent_Populate() command):

- `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`
- `BUILD_COMMAND`
- `INSTALL_COMMAND`
- `TEST_COMMAND`

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_getproperties (just the paragraph above)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev and @Mizux I can follow the correct way to do it.

```
FetchContent_Declare( libpng
        GIT_REPOSITORY      https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android.git
        GIT_TAG             master
        UPDATE_DISCONNECTED TRUE
        STEP_TARGETS        update)

FetchContent_GetProperties(libpng)
if (NOT libpng_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(libpng)
    add_subdirectory("${libpng_SOURCE_DIR}" ${libpng_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()

exec_program("${CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK}/ndk-build.cmd"
        ${libpng_BINARY_DIR}
        ARGS NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${libpng_SOURCE_DIR} APP_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI})
```

and then linking the libraries

```
target_link_libraries( project
        PRIVATE
            ${libpng_SOURCE_DIR}/obj/local/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpng.a
        )
```

Comment: `exec_program` is now deprecated in favor of `execute_process`:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html